# VSCode shortcut to move cursor from terminal to code, but keep terminal window open

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm on Mac. I use `` CTRL + ` `` to toggle the terminal window on and off, but is there a shortcut to jump from terminal window back to code window, but leave the terminal window open?

Something like `CTRL + w` in VIM.

Comment: on windows it is `Ctrl+1`

Comment: You probably want `workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup`` which is unbound by default.  It will go back to whichever editor group was last active.

Comment: @rioV8 `Ctrl+1` works on Mac, COOL!